# Finite summation of series involving factorials and exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

I would like to compute the following summation of series:
$$F(k,a)=\sum_{m=-1}^{k}(-1)^m\frac{k!}{(k-m)!}a^{k-m},$$
where $a$ is a known constant, $k$ and $m$ are integers. $x!$ indicates the factorial value of $x$.

WolframAlpha gave me a result:
$$F(k,a)=(-1)^ke^{-a}\Gamma(k+1,-a)-\frac{a^{k+1}}{k+1},$$
considering k is an integer:
$$\Gamma(k+1,-a)=k!e^a\cdot e_k(-a),$$
then
$$F(k,a)=(-1)^kk!e_k(-a)-\frac{a^{k+1}}{k+1},$$
here $e_k(x)$ is the exponentional sum function: $e_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$

I have checked that this result is correct for $k=0$. When assuming that it also holds for $k=N$, how to prove the correctness for $k=N+1$ using the constructive proof method?

Thanks very much indeed!

Comment: Did you try Wolframalpha?

Comment: Why is the sum starting at -1?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Thanks for your notification! Although WolframAlpha could give a result, it doesn't post the inner steps and I couldn't prove its correctness.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Well, it's just a part of my complicated computation and this summation should start at -1 for my problem.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I have re-edited the question, could you help me to prove the correctness of the WolframAlpha's result? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the summation index to $\,n=k-m\,$ gives the following, equivalent to the posted form:

$$
\begin{align}
F(k,a) &= \sum_{n=0}^{k+1}\,(-1)^{k-n}\,\frac{k!}{n!}\,a^{n} \\[5px]
 &= (-1)^k\, k!\, \sum_{n=0}^{k+1}\,\frac{(-1)^{-n}a^{n}}{n!} \\[5px]
 &= (-1)^k\, k!\, \sum_{n=0}^{k+1}\, \frac{(-a)^{n}}{n!} \\[5px]
 &= (-1)^k \,k!\, e_{k+1}(-a)
\end{align}
$$